# Unable to restore packages in ASP.net application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nuget-package-restore

I pulled the latest code from 
 https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/dev

Without making any changes to the code, when I enter the command `dnu restore`. 
I get this error message "Unable to locate Dependency".

Below is my error message.

```
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect >= 0.1.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISPlatformHandler >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Tooling.Razor >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener >= 0.1.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles >= 1.0.0-*
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc >= 1.0.0-*
```

Can anyone help me build this application?

Comment: Did you check you have proper [NuGet configuration for VNext packages](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Configuring-the-feed-used-by-dnu-to-restore-packages)?

Comment: yes, looks like the branch is unstable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `dev` branch which is in a bad shape now because we're transitioning to `dotnet` and we're also performing a lot of renames. The packages that fail to restore have just been pushed on the feed (about 10 min ago).

Restore should work now but the branch is still unstable.

Comment: Thank you Victor, So which is the latest and most stable branch you suggest to use. The master branch looks pretty old , with updates done 2 months ago. It would be great , if you also mention the dnx version compatible for that branch